# css transition from a tutorial not working even with -webkit- and -moz- prefixes

Tags: css, css-transitions

This may have an obvious answer, but I'm just not seeing it. I updated this code to correct for having the wrong `top` value for `article section h1`. I also added a `:hover` trigger for `article section h1`. Otherwise, this is the same code I took from webdesigner magazine to demonstrate an animated title effect, but nothing is happening in either FF or Chrome. I added the -webkit- and -moz- prefixes to the transition style, but still, nothing. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```css
    body,html {
 display:block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: white;
 color:black;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
nav {
 position:fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 9999;
 background: white;
}
article {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 5em;
}
article section {
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 width: 100%;
} 
article section:target {
 left: 0;
 opacity: 1;
 z-index: 9999;
}
article section h1 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0em;
 left: 0;
 font-size: 4em;
 width: 100%;
 color:black;
 
}
article section h1:hover {
 text-shadow: 0 998em 2 em #000;
 transition: text-shadow 1.5s;
 -webkit-transition: text-shadow 1.5s;
 -moz-transition:text-shadow 1.5s;
}
nav {
 display:block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 2em;
 text-align: center;
}
nav a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 1em 2em;
 margin-right: 1em;
}
nav > a:hover {
 border-bottom: .5em solid #c00;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
      <a href="#first">Option</a>
      <a href="#second">Option</a>
      <a href="#third">Option</a>
      
     </nav>
     
     <article>
      <section id="first">
       <h1>First title</h1>
      </section>
      <section id="second">
       <h1>Second title</h1>
      </section>
      <section id="third">
       <h1>Third title</h1>
      </section>
     </article>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yqsuy7w/)

Comment: Your fiddle is defective. With that CSS, your `section`s will never appear so you can see the transition working. And for that reason, your real intentions are unclear. Please re-write your code, so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the expected result is, but anyway: You have `top: -1000em;` in the rule for `article section h1`, and there is no other rule which would change this position. So these `h1` elements will  remain invisible (because they are far off the screen). Change that to `top: 0em;` for a beginning, and then look for the transitions...

Comment: you have a point here, author's Fiddle is defective. But that doesn't exactly answer his question. This could be a comment.

Comment: @VictorGodoi The question is unclear. The only transition there is is a text-shadow transition, but no trigger (hover or similar) for it. But exactly that text will anyways remain invisible with the given setting, so yes, my answer isat least an answer to why that transitioned text is invisible.

Comment: @Johannes: Thanks! It's a defective tutorial -- the code is wrong. Taking your advice, now I can see article section h1, but as you note, there is no trigger for the transition. I'll put in a trigger.